# Using knex.js updates existing column with results of select query

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, knex.js

Product (id, currentdraw, totaldraw, ratio)

Product is my table

I want to use currentdraw and totaldraw to update ratio

Here is my code

```
Product.updateRatio = function(pid, cb) {
db('product')
  .where({
    productid : pid
  })
  .select('currentdraw', 'totaldraw')
  .then(function(ratiolist) {
    db('product')
      .where({
        productid : pid
      })
      .update({
        ratio : ratiolist.currentdraw / ratiolist.totaldraw
      })
      cb(null, ratiolist);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    cb(new GeneralErrors.Database());
    console.log('updateRatio');
  });
}
```

When I run the code, no error occuring but ratio column doesn't update.

I don't know where is wrong.

Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that your `ratiolist` is array instead of an object, add `console.dir(ratiolist)` to check what is returned from the first query:

```
function(ratiolist) {
  // here ratiolist is an array
  db('product')
    .where({
      productid : pid
    })
    .update({
      // undefined / undefined is NaN
      ratio : ratiolist.currentdraw / ratiolist.totaldraw 
    })
    // second query  is not yet ran when this callback is called
    // try to use promise chains...
    cb(null, ratiolist);
})
```

Better way to do this query would be:

```
// return value passed as promise instead of callback
Product.updateRatio = function(pid) {
  return db('product')
    .where('productid', pid)
    .update({ 
      ratio : db.raw('?? / ??', ['currentdraw', 'totaldraw'])
    })
    .then(() => db('product').where('productid', pid));
}
```

If you insist using callbacks this should work:

```
Product.updateRatio = function(pid, cb) {
  db('product')
    .where('productid', pid)
    .update({ 
      ratio : db.raw('?? / ??', ['currentdraw', 'totaldraw'])
    })
    .then(() => db('product').where('productid', pid))
    .then(ratiolist => cb(null, ratiolist));
}
```

Comment: it works perfectly ! thanks a lot. My reputation is not enough to upvote your answer. sorry